# Probability of $1 bill

Tags: probability, probability-theory, problem-solving

Suppose you have a wallet that contains either a 1 bill or a 10 bill (with equal probability). You add a 1 bill. Later you reach into your wallet and randomly remove a bill. It's a 1 bill. What's the probability that the bill remaining in the wallet is a 1 bill?

This is all I have so far:

A= event that $1 bill is chosen

B= event that $10 bill is chosen

P(A) = $\frac{2}{3}$

P(B)= $\frac{1}{3}$

Comment: Use Bayes Theorem

Comment: Once you've defined that $A$, you don't need to define your $B$. Pulling a 10 dollar bill is exactly the same as not pulling a 1 dollar bill, so that's "not $A$". Instead, you should assign a letter to which bill was in the wallet originally.

Comment: As an aside, $P(A)\neq \frac{2}{3}$ but rather $P(A)=\frac{3}{4}$.  In an effort to conserve the number of variable names being used, rather than calling $B$ the event that a $\$10$ bill is chosen, just call that $A^c$ instead, and you should get $P(A^c)=\frac{1}{4}$

Comment: In order to see why $P(A)=\frac{3}{4}$, let us define another event... since you already used $B$ to avoid confusion, I'll name it $C$ instead.  Let $C$ be the event that wallet originally contained a $\$1$, meaning $C^c$ is the event that the wallet originally contained a $\$10$.  We have $P(A)=P(A\cap C)+P(A\cap C^c) = P(C)P(A\mid C)+P(C^c)P(A\mid C^c) = \frac{1}{2}\times \frac{2}{2} + \frac{1}{2}\times \frac{1}{2}=\frac{3}{4}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you have two possible configurations before the draw.  Enumerate those possibilities with the possible draws from each:

- 1 & 1

  - draw first 1
  - draw second 1
- 1 & 10

  - draw 1
  - draw 10

Consider the draws here where you took out a 1... you can count how many second draws will result in a 1 versus a 10.

Related: check out the famous [Monty Hall problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monty_Hall_problem)

Comment: So the probability is 2/3?

Comment: @355durch113, right!  Given you just drew a 1, the follow up possibilities are drawing the "second" 1, drawing the "first" 1, or drawing a 10.